Style a plain dropdown menu in SwiftUI
I’m trying to create a simple dropdown button in SwiftUI on macOS. Normally I would expect to use something like this:
MenuButton("☰") {
    Button(action: { print("Something") }) {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "questionmark.circle")
            Text("Something")
        }
    }
    Button(action: { print("Something Else") }) {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.circle")
            Text("Something Else")
        }
    }
}
.menuButtonStyle(BorderlessButtonMenuButtonStyle())

The .menuButtonStyle(BorderlessButtonMenuButtonStyle()) shows only the menu icon (☰)

without the drop down

However, MenuButton has been deprecated in favour of Menu, which is fine, but I then need to modify it with .menuStyle, and can’t find the equivalent of BorderlessButtonMenuButtonStyle
What would be the equivalent for Menu to suppress the drop down arrow?

As per the documentation (which may be somewhat innacurate since .buttonStyle(.borderless) does display a down arrow):

borderlessButton Deprecated
Use menuStyle(_:) with button and buttonStyle(_:) with
borderless.

        Menu("☰") {
                Button(action: { print("Something") }) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "questionmark.circle")
                        Text("Something")
                    }
                }
                Button(action: { print("Something Else") }) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.circle")
                        Text("Something Else")
                    }
                }
            }
            .menuStyle(.button)
            .buttonStyle(.plain)


That’s it. The documentation didn’t lead so obviously to the .plain style. Thanks
